# Magento 2 - Edit order programmatically without canceling

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically, edit-order, cancel-orders

I want to edit any order programmatically.

The tutorials that I am getting is canceling current order and creating new one. But I need something different, I want to edit it without canceling or creating new one.

There is a similar post here **[Magento 2: How to edit existing Order without cancel?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211837/magento-2-how-to-edit-existing-order-without-cancel) But there** is not accepted answer on that post.

Please help me find solution on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: How to edit existing Order without cancel?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211837/magento-2-how-to-edit-existing-order-without-cancel)

Comment: No bro, no answer is mark correct on that question which you have shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, you can programmatically edit an order without canceling or creating a new one by using the order repository and service classes. Here are the general steps you can follow:

1. Use the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` class to load the order you want to edit by its ID or increment ID.

```
$orderId = 1;
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
```

2. Use the `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` class to update the order's data.

```
$order->setShippingAddress($newShippingAddress);
$order->setBillingAddress($newBillingAddress);
```

3. Use the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` class to save the updated order.

```
$this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

It's important to note that, depending on the type of change you want to make, some adjustments might be necessary, such as recalculating the order totals, updating the order status, or updating the order items.

You should also make sure that the changes you are making are valid and that they don't break any rules or constraints in the order management system.

You can also use the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface` class to update the order's status, shipping and billing address, payment method, and other information.

```
$this->orderManagement->setShippingAddress($orderId, $newShippingAddress);
$this->orderManagement->setBillingAddress($orderId, $newBillingAddress);
$this->orderManagement->setPaymentMethod($orderId, $newPaymentMethod);
```

It's important to check the documentation of the Order Management and Order Repository classes to understand the methods and properties that are available, and also check the expected input and output of those methods before using them.

I hope it will help !!!